# Doubt on the Voltage Regulator Application with LiPo Battery

Tags: voltage, power, voltage-regulator, heat, thermal

If I have a LiPo battery with the maximum voltage of 12V and I want to use it to power a 5v(L7805) voltage regulator. Assuming the maximum current passing through the regulator is 500mA. From datasheet, the thermal resistance is 50°C/W.

Does that mean that it would generate a power loss of 3.5W and it would raise the voltage regulator's temperature by 175°C? The maximum operating temperature of the voltage regulator is 150°C. Would that means I need to drop the input voltage of the regulator?

**Additional info from OP comments:**

I am not able to get a switching regulator and the great power loss is not a concern. Would the thing work if I stack multiple voltage regulator together?

Comment: That's exactly what it means. Alternatively, you could use a heatsink. But keep in mind that all that power is just being wasted--you should look into a switching regulator, not a linear one, for this level of voltage difference and current.

Comment: If I am not able to get a switching regulator and the great power loss is not a concerned. Would the thing work if I stack multiple voltage regulator together? I did some rough calculation. If I am constructing the circuit without using resistor, using four voltage regulator would raise each temperature by 90°C.

Comment: Remember that heatsinks are an option as well. With a heatsink, you can reduce the case-to-ambient thermal resistance.

Comment: Have you calculated the maximum value of a series resistor between 12V and the regulator?  And what would the worst case regulator and resistor power be?

Comment: By the way, if I use heatsink instead of resistor to handle to power loss. It would give me a larger allowance on the battery voltage drop, right?

Comment: A series of high rated power would help but the situation in here is  I am using battery to power up the circuit and the battery voltage would drop. The input voltage of the regulator must be at least 7.5V due to 2.5V dropout voltage. Using resistor would reduce the range of working battery voltage in this circuit.

Comment: Considering that it can't even handle 12V without a heat sink, yes it will give you a larger allowance. However there are practical limits to the size of heat sink and cooling requirements (a large heat sink is no good if put inside a case with no airflow!).

Comment: "Using resistor would reduce the range of working battery voltage in this circuit" - yes. However a '12V' lipo battery should not be discharged below 10V. The main problem with a resistor is it has to dissipate power and gets hot, so you might as well just use a heat sink.

Comment: I manufactured a product designed many years ago with the same characteristics you described.   I used a 5 Watt, 5.1 &Omega; serial resistor and not one field failure in 20 years.  No heatsink.  Discharge Cutoff voltage is 9V, so you will need a slightly lower value resistor. I would think a battery powered device would require a switcher.  You will be significantly reducing the life of the battery.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations are absolutely right.

Given your restrictions and goals: YES you could use several cascaded linear regulators (with different output voltages, of course, and respecting the required dropout voltages) and/or series resistors, in order to distribute the heat dissipation across several components.

**However, a heatsink looks like a far simpler and better solution.** Let's say you want to derate the maximum junction temperature to 80% while being able to operate the regulator up to 50 C ambient temperature.

That would mean a maximum junction temperature rise of 70 C. At 3.5 W dissipation, you'll need a 20 C/W junction-to-ambient thermal resistance. The TO-220 junction-to-case thermal resistance is just 5 C/W, so **you would need a heatsink providing a 15 C/W case-to-ambient thermal resistance**. That can be perfectly achieved with a passive heatsink (which could even by realised by bolting the regulator to your case/chassis if available).